# Which points of the curves-solution are such that the tangent pass through the origin?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2+xy+y^2}{x^2}$.

**Personnal question :** Which points of the curves-solutions are such that the tangent pass through the origin?

I know that a such line is on the form $y =\frac{dy}{dx} x $, but I don't know how to find such points.

Do I have to use Rolle's theorem or it generalization to look for the existence of a such point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solve: $dy/dx = \frac{y}{x}$, where $dy/dx$ get replaced by the RHS (right hand side) of your expression. However, do check the sign of $y/x$ holds for all quadrants as it holds for the first quadrant (ie $x.0$ and $y>0$).